# Connected service does not parse SOAP response correctly

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I am working with this SOAP web service in a .NET Framework project. I inspect the XML content of requests and responses, and everything looks good. But the SOAP client (the one Visual Studio creates via Connected Services thing) does not map the response correctly to the entity class.

Here is the request XML.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">OrderList</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OrderListRequest xmlns="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
      <auth xmlns="">
        <appKey>**redacted**</appKey>
        <appSecret>**redacted**</appSecret>
      </auth>
      <searchData xmlns="">
        <productId xsi:nil="true" />
        <status xsi:nil="true" />
        <orderNumber>**redacted**</orderNumber>
        <productSellerCode xsi:nil="true" />
        <sameDayDelivery xsi:nil="true" />
        <sortForUpdateDate>false</sortForUpdateDate>
      </searchData>
      <pagingData xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" />
    </OrderListRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here is the response.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header />
  <env:Body>
    <ns3:OrderListResponse xmlns="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
      <result>
        <status>success</status>
      </result>
      <pagingData>
        <currentPage>0</currentPage>
        <pageSize>100</pageSize>
        <totalCount>1</totalCount>
        <pageCount>1</pageCount>
      </pagingData>
      <orderList>
        <order>
          <citizenshipId>**redacted**</citizenshipId>
          <createDate>02/10/2020 14:46</createDate>
          <id>**redacted**</id>
          <orderNumber>**redacted**</orderNumber>
          <paymentType>1</paymentType>
          <status>2</status>
        </order>
      </orderList>
    </ns3:OrderListResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

As it is visible in the response XML, I get all the information I want perfectly. But as you can see in the screenshot below, all I'm getting in the response object is the `citizenshipId`, and everything else is either null or the default value for its type.

[image]

What could be the problem here? I'm a newbie in .NET so I don't even know how to Google this. I tried a few searches but nothing yielded any related results.

The WSDL is publicly available at https://api.n11.com/ws/OrderService.wsdl.